# SDL_WM_SetCaption not working

Tags: c++, sdl

any idea why the following code isn't working? Nothing happens when it's called, the window title is still untitled. I'm on Ubuntu linux.

```
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Window Title", "Icon Title");
    SDL_Surface* screen =  SDL_SetVideoMode( 512, 512, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF );
    Vector2 center =  Vector2(256,256);
    const char* c =  "test";
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( c, 0 );
    SDL_Event event;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may not be at fault.  Ubuntu may be responsible for that one.  Or rather, the window manager/compositor Compiz that it uses:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/257391

Switching from Compiz to Metacity could help you figure out if you are affected by this bug as well.

There may be something else going on: I don't get a title when I call SetCaption after SetVideoMode but I do get one when I set the caption before, which is not the behavior you are observing.

Comment: Turned out it was a bug in the window manager. After I updated, it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Make your first call to [`SDL_WM_SetCaption`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_WM_SetCaption) after `SDL_SetVideoMode` has been called.  Also, remove the second test call. If you are using SDL 1.3, (it sounds like you are using 1.2, so you can probably ignore this), call [`SDL_SetWindowTitle`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_SetWindowTitle):